# Converting coordinates in Florida, USA?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, united-states

I have an point location and the information given is:

Easting: 519122.06

Northing: 1290630.07

Original thought was it's UTM, but does not appear to be correct because I know the point needs to be in Florida. Is there another system similar to UTM?  I need to convert these to decimal degrees.

Comment: http://epsg.io/?q=florida gives 90 possibilities, may be you need to ask the data supplier

Comment: Thank *you* for giving @radouxju enough information to answer your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two UTM zones covering Florida : 16 and 17, but you are indeed not going anywhere with your coordinates. Northing with UTM starts at 0 at the equator, so you would be 1290 km North of the equator in UTM (which is far too South)

My best guess in NAD83/Florida West, with map unit in US feet (you fall in Hillsborough bay),  :[image: Florida West]

but you should be aware that there could be other possibilities. For instance, it could also be  NAD83/Florida East, then you are right in the center

[image: Florida East]

Comment: That's where the point should be! how did you convert it? I had originally used the UTM zone 17 @radouxju

Comment: It should definitely be Florida West 0902 and that point is right where it should be it. Now, I'm just unsure of how to take all the points I have in this format and plot them in arcmap. @radouxju

Comment: Thank you! I think I have it figured out, I guess I was unsure and thinking it was UTM and didn't realize a state plane could be formatted like that.

Comment: use "define projection" to change the coordinate system of your points into Florida West. DO NOT use project.